# Generic MySQL Select All Function

Tags: php, mysql

I write a lot of SELECT * FROM... kind of queries in my web sites. I'd like to write a function that looks after this for me so I can call on it more quickly, without using more advanced techniques like PDO and OOP. Im just confused on how I would call the data I retrieve from the database, particularly when looping through the array's results.

I'd love something like this:

```
function selectAll($tableName, $limitAmount) {
    global $dbConnection;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id LIMIT $limitAmount");
    $row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $row_result;
}
```

Say it was a bunch of news posts. Id like to loop through the results in one of the typical ways:

```
// CALL THE FUNCTION
selectAll('news_table', '10');

// SOMEHOW LOOP THROUGH RESULTS??
do {
    echo "<h2>".$row_result['title']."</h2>";
} while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Obviously this isn't how I loop through the bespoke results of a function. Im not even sure if my function is correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to return a result inside the function and call the actual function. My bad. Updated now.

Comment: where are you calling that function?

Comment: Apologies... forgot that, and the return $row_result; I have updated the original post.

Comment: Loop and fetch the results to construct an array, then return that array. You can then foreach that array to get each result, outside the function.

Comment: Dan, could you illustrate that for me with some demo code? I'm not quite 100% on the syntax! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in having such a function called like yours.

Just make it like this

```
function fetchAll($query) {
  $res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
  $a   = array();
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $a[]=$row;
  }
  return $a;
}
```

and use it with whatever query:

```
$data = fetchAll("SELECT * FROM news_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

An SQL query being a **powerful program** itself. Do not reduce it's power to silly selects.
Use SQL to represent data processing logic and this helper function to avoid repetitions.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for the sound logic and advice. This is perfect. It's what's commonly 3 or 4 lines of code down to 1. How would one check if there's any rows in the array? Often I check if there's rows to show, if not, I display a message, or do nothing at all etc.

Comment: You could use `foreach` with empty arrays too - it just won't output anything. If you still need to check - simply `if ($data) {` will do

Comment: One last question actually. What's the best way to find out how many rows there are? I often like to do something depending on the NUMBER of rows there are. I normally use $total = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Been using your function without a hitch last night. However, can I echo out data without initiating the for each loop, say for when I am retrieving only 1 row? I have tried just using echo $data['column'] without first starting the loop, but it returned an empty value.

Comment: To elaborate...

Lets say I use your function above to get the current blog post:

    $post = fetchAll("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$get_id' LIMIT 1");

... and then I would like to get all comments related to that post:

    $comments = fetchAll("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '".$post['id']."' ORDER BY date ASC");

It won't work because the $post['id'] returns an empty value because we have not instantiated the foreach loop yet.